# Smarty foreach loop - syntax error: invalid attribute name: '$arrTest'

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I'm passing an array to smarty which looks like this:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
        array(1) {
            ["name"]=>
                string(6) "Test 1"
        }
    [1]=>
        array(1) {
            ["name"]=>
                string(6) "Test 2"
        }
}
```

When I try to iterate over it using:

```
{foreach $arrTest as $tmp}
    Test
{/foreach}
```

I get the error: invalid attribute name: '$arrTest'

Smarty version 3.1.4

I've seen some people saying I need to turn off magic_quotes_runtime, but it's already off. So is  magic_quotes_gpc for that matter.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you assign the array to smarty? `$smarty->assign('arrTest', $yourArray);` and your code should work just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{foreach from=$arrTest item=arr}
   {$arr.name}
{/foreach}
```